# How to stop a div above the footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, sticky

I have read many posts about this issue, but none of them are helping aid the issue I am having. I want to get the nav_bar on the side of the page to stop right about the footer (exactly where the content div ends.) I am sorry, I am not very good with javascript/jQuery. haha

Here is my code for the nav:

```
<div id="section">
        <div id="navbar">
            <div id="navbar_contents">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/nav_bar/nav_top.jpg" width="107" height="55" alt="top"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/nav_bar/nav_portfolio.jpg" width="107" height="55" alt="portfolio"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/nav_bar/nav_about.jpg" width="107" height="55" alt="about"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/nav_bar/nav_contact.jpg" width="107" height="55" alt="contact"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/nav_bar/nav_resume.jpg" width="107" height="55" alt="resume"></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
  <div id="content">
  <h1>THE TOP</h1>
  <div id="clear">
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#section #navbar {
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 2px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 2px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 2px #000000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    padding-right: 23px;
    position: fixed;
}

#section #navbar #navbar_contents {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

#section #navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#section #content {
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 2000px;
    width: 610px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 200px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 2px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 2px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 2px #000000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: Can you provide a basic and clear drawing of what you want ?

Comment: If you provide a picture it would be much easier to code an example up

Answer (score 1):

## Update

Change your CSS:

```
#section {
width: 940px;
height: 1500px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
padding-left: 0px;
}
```

The `margin-top` you had was causing the nav-bar to be pushed down slightly too far.

Comment: Do you mean: $("#navbar").height($("#content").height()); ?

Comment: @roasted I did indeed, updating

Comment: I did not want to adjust the size of the nav_bar div to the size of the content div, I want to have the nav_bar div stop scrolling where the content div ends, that way it does not overlap over the footer.

Comment: @PixelReaper I assumed #navbar was a container, and so you would just set `overflow: auto` to the container after changing the container height

Comment: Alright. Yeah, that code does not seem to be working on the nav bar. I am sorry, I am really new to this.

Comment: this is what the page currently looks like. http://jsfiddle.net/np3MY/embedded/result/ I want the div on the left to stop scrolling once it reaches the end of the content div, and not overflowing onto the footer.

Comment: @PixelReaper NOW I understand your question. The navbar and content will need to be wrapped in a `div` separate from the `footer` div for this to work the way you want

Comment: @PixelReaper See the latest update. Change the CSS of `section` - it worked for me

Comment: They are wrapped in seperate divs. haha. The reason why I have the margin_top: 20px; is because I don't want the div going up any further. I do not believe that is messing it up. you need jQuery to tell the navigation box to not scroll down any further.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29131/discussion-between-evan-and-pixel-reaper)